# Temporal tables in Teradata: different behaviour as compared to the documentation

Tags: sql, teradata, temporal-tables

I just started exploring Teradata's temporal table implementation and it seems that my version of Teradata (16.20) is not behaving in the way as it is supposed to:

[Example is taken from Teradata documentation](https://www.docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-Temporal-Table-Support/March-2019/Getting-Started/Temporal-Statements)

Create temporal table:

```
   CREATE MULTISET TABLE Policy(
      Policy_ID INTEGER,
      Customer_ID INTEGER,
      Policy_Type CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
      Policy_Details CHAR(40),
      Validity PERIOD(DATE) NOT NULL AS VALIDTIME
      )
   PRIMARY INDEX(Policy_ID);
```

And insert row data with valid time period'(2009-10-01,2010-10-01)'

```
   INSERT INTO Policy
      (Policy_ID, Customer_ID, Policy_Type, Policy_Details, Validity)
      VALUES (541008, 246824626, 'AU', 'STD-CH-345-NXY-00',
              PERIOD(DATE '2009-10-01', 2010-10-01));
   INSERT INTO Policy
      (Policy_ID, Customer_ID, Policy_Type, Policy_Details, Validity)
      VALUES (99999, 11111, 'AU', 'STD-CH-345-NXY-00',
              PERIOD(DATE '2009-10-01', until_changed));
```

If I now query ([corresponding to the doc](https://www.docs.teradata.com/r/Teradata-VantageTM-Temporal-Table-Support/March-2019/SQL-Data-Manipulation-Language-Temporal-Forms/SELECT/SELECT-...-INTO-Temporal-Forms/Usage-Notes))

```
SELECT * FROM Policy;
```

I should actually only get the results which are still valid (intersection not null with today '2023-02-01'--'9999-12-31') and without the validity column
so

```
   Policy_ID  Customer_ID  Policy_Type  Policy_Details
   ---------  -----------  -----------  ---------------
    99999      11111      'AU'     'STD-CH-345-NXY-00'
```

- but I get the whole table (and complete history):

```
   Policy_ID  Customer_ID  Policy_Type  Policy_Details   Validity
   ---------  -----------  -----------  ---------------  -------
    99999      11111           'AU'     'STD-CH-345-NXY-00'   (2009-10-01,9999-12-31)
    541008    246824626        'AU'     'STD-CH-345-NXY-00'   (2009-10-01,2010-10-01)
```

which is exactly the same result as when queried via the nonsequenced query

```
NONSEQUENCED VALIDTIME SELECT * FROM Policy;
```

Why is this the case, am I missing something? Is it possible, that my "select" somehow defaults to a different behaviour? How can I make sure that the temporal versioning is actually working the way it should?

Comment: I have never understood what happens if you don't specify your validtime.  Run it this way: `validtime as of current_date;  SELECT  * FROM Policy;`  If there's some documentation of default behavior, I've never been able to find it.

Comment: Your system defaults to *ANSI Temporal*, check the differences [here](https://www.docs.teradata.com/r/Enterprise_IntelliFlex_VMware/Teradata-VantageTM-ANSI-Temporal-Table-Support-17.20/ANSI-Temporal-Concepts/ANSI-Temporal-and-Teradata-Temporal). `SET SESSION CURRENT VALIDTIME; SELECT * FROM Policy;` is what you need.

Comment: Yes, Teradata supports two different kinds of Temporal syntax / behavior - proprietary Teradata Temporal and ANSI Temporal (with separate manuals). The system "dbscontrol" setting determines whether SET SESSION ANSIQUALIFIER; or SET SESSION CURRENT VALIDTIME AND CURRENT TRANSACTIONTIME; is in effect at logon (before you explicitly set a temporal qualifier).

Comment: @dnoeth (also Andrew, Fred): Thanks! I'll check the behaviour (and also definitely the ANSI documention) when I get the chance tomorrow. I was aware that Teradata supports the ANSI standard as well, but  I would have never anticipated this conflict. So, basically there is ANSI system-versioning, ANSI-validtime (application time) and Teradata temporal? It's interesting that things like "NONSEQUENCED / SEQUENCED etc." work - it almost seems like it can change on the fly. Probably one should stick to one interpretation to avoid conflicts?

Comment: There's a system default, but you can use both ANSI & Teradata Temporal syntax, getting the best of both worlds :-)